# Custom control icons for images in fabric js

Tags: fabricjs

> This code works fine in fabric js version 1.5 but it doesnt work in
>   the latest fabric version 2.4.0.It throws the following error:Uncaught
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'fire' of undefined and Uncaught
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined.Please refer this
>   fiddle link(https://codepen.io/elhoussinelaidi/pen/RRrLzv) this is
>   written in fabric version 1.5.but i want this functionality to be
>   working fine in fabric version 2.4.0.Could anyone please help me out to solve this problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Custom Control</title>

  <script src="https://static.filestackapi.com/v3/filestack.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <body>
    <div id="canvas-container" class="over">
  <div class="canvas-container" style="width: 800px; height: 600px; position: relative; -webkit-user-select: none;">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
  <script type="text/javascript">



    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var DIMICON = 15;
var HideControls = {
  'tl': true,
  'tr': true,
  'bl': true,
  'br': true,
  'ml': false,
  'mt': false,
  'mr': false,
  'mb': false,
  'mtr': false
};

var dataImage = [
  "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/streamline-interface/60/cell-8-10-120.png", /*scale*/
  "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ui-color/512/Untitled-12-128.png", /*delete*/
  "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-messaging-productivity-1/128/sync-16.png", /*rotate*/
  "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-messaging-productivity-1/128/write-compose-16.png", /*change text*/
  "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-messaging-productivity-1/128/save-16.png" /*save*/
];
//********override*****//
fabric.Object.prototype._drawControl = function(control, ctx, methodName, left, top,styleOverride) {
  if (!this.isControlVisible(control)) {
    return;
  }
  var SelectedIconImage = new Image();
  var size = this.cornerSize;
  /*  fabric.isVML() ||*/
  this.transparentCorners || ctx.clearRect(left, top, size, size);
  switch (control) {
    case 'tl':
      /*delete*/
      SelectedIconImage.src = dataImage[1];
      break;
    case 'tr':
      /*scale*/
      SelectedIconImage.src = dataImage[0];
      break;
    case 'bl':
      /*scale*/
      SelectedIconImage.src = dataImage[0];
      break;
    case 'br':
      /*rotate*/
      SelectedIconImage.src = dataImage[2];
      break;
    default:
      ctx[methodName](left, top, size, size);
  }

  if (control == 'tl' || control == 'tr' || control == 'bl' || control == 'br') {
    try {
      ctx.drawImage(SelectedIconImage, left, top, DIMICON, DIMICON);
    } catch (e) {
      ctx[methodName](left, top, size, size);
    }
  }
}

//override prorotype _setCornerCursor to change the corner cusrors
fabric.Canvas.prototype._setCornerCursor = function(corner, target) {
  if (corner === 'mtr' && target.hasRotatingPoint) {
    this.setCursor(this.rotationCursor);

  } else if (corner == "tr" || corner == "bl") {
    this.setCursor('sw-resize');

  } else if (corner == "tl" || corner == "br") {
    this.setCursor('pointer');
  }

  else {
    this.setCursor(this.defaultCursor);
    return false;
  }
};
fabric.Canvas.prototype._getActionFromCorner = function(target, corner) {
  var action = 'drag';
  if (corner) {
    switch (corner) {
      case 'ml':
      case 'mr':
        action = 'scaleX';
        break;
      case 'mt':
      case 'mb':
        action = 'scaleY';
        break;
      case 'mtr':
        action = 'rotate';
        break;
        /**ADD **/
      case 'br':
        action = 'rotate';
        break;
      case 'tl': //delete function if mouse down
        action = 'delete';
        canvas.remove(canvas.getActiveObject());
        break;

      default:
        action = 'scale';
    }
    return action;
  }
}

fabric.Canvas.prototype._performTransformAction = function(e, transform, pointer) {
    var x = pointer.x,
      y = pointer.y,
      target = transform.target,
      action = transform.action;

    if (action === 'rotate') {
      this._rotateObject(x, y);
      this._fire('rotating', target, e);
    } else if (action === 'scale') {
      this._onScale(e, transform, x, y);
      this._fire('scaling', target, e);
    } else if (action === 'scaleX') {
      this._scaleObject(x, y, 'x');
      this._fire('scaling', target, e);
    } else if (action === 'scaleY') {
      this._scaleObject(x, y, 'y');
      this._fire('scaling', target, e);
    }
    /**ADD**/
    else if (action === 'delete') {
      //do nothing, because here function executed when mouse moves
    }
    /**ADD END**/
    else {
      this._translateObject(x, y);
      this._fire('moving', target, e);
      this.setCursor(this.moveCursor);
    }
  }
fabric.Image.fromURL('http://serio.piiym.net/CVBla/txtboard/thumb/1260285874089s.jpg', function(img) {
  img.top = 0;
  img.left = 0;
  img.setControlsVisibility(HideControls);
  canvas.add(img);
});
canvas.renderAll();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adapt `fabric.Canvas.prototype._performTransformAction` and `fabric.Canvas.prototype._getActionFromCorner` to 2.4 fabric version
Check here:https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WaRaed
You can also use [this](https://github.com/pixolith/fabricjs-customise-controls-extension) for custom controls